# BeagleBone Black: Unable to get u-boot prompt

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

I am trying to build u-boot for my BeagleBone Black.

I have properly compiled the MLO and u-boot.img and loaded into the sd-card.

However, when i try to boot, i get the following log:

> U-Boot SPL 2020.07-00717-gfee68b9 (Jul 17 2020 - 09:36:15) Trying to
> boot from MMC1
>
> U-Boot 2020.07-00717-gfee68b9 (Jul 17 2020 - 09:36:15)
>
> CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1 Model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black DRAM:  512
> MiB WDT:   Started with servicing (60s timeout) NAND:  0 MiB MMC:
> OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1 Loading Environment from FAT... ***
> Warning - bad CRC, using default environment
>
> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC Net:   eth2:
> ethernet@4a100000, eth3: usb_ether Hit any key to stop autoboot:  2
> 1  0  switch to partitions #0, OK mmc0 is current device SD/MMC
> found on device 0 switch to partitions #0, OK mmc0 is current device
> Scanning mmc 0:1... switch to partitions #0, OK mmc0 is current device
> SD/MMC found on device 0 switch to partitions #0, OK mmc1(part 0) is
> current device Scanning mmc 1:1... switch to partitions #0, OK
> mmc1(part 0) is current device SD/MMC found on device 1 Error:
> "bootcmd_nand0" not defined starting USB... Bus usb@47401800: Port not
> available. ethernet@4a100000 Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to
> complete......... TIMEOUT ! using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in
> STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS
> ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config #2: 2
> mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up!
>
> BOOTP broadcast 1 BOOTP broadcast 2 . . BOOTP broadcast 29
>
> Retry time exceeded; starting again missing environment variable:
> pxeuuid Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00000000 using musb-hdrc, OUT
> ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC
> de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost!
> high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS
> network up!
> *** ERROR: `serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0000000 using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up! *** ERROR:` serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/000000 using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC
> de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc:
> peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet
> Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up!
> *** ERROR: `serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00000 using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up! *** ERROR:` serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0000 using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST
> MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq
> lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB
> RNDIS network up!
> *** ERROR: `serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/000 using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up! *** ERROR:` serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00 using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST
> MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq
> lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB
> RNDIS network up!
> *** ERROR: `serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0 using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up! *** ERROR:` serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm-am33xx-am335x using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN
> ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00
> RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config
> #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up!
> *** ERROR: `serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm-am33xx using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up! *** ERROR:` serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS
> ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready
> musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA,
> Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up!
> *** ERROR: `serverip' not set Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00 RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up! *** ERROR:` serverip' not set Config file not found starting USB... Bus usb@47401800: Port not available. using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN
> ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00
> RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config
> #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up!
>
> BOOTP broadcast 1 BOOTP broadcast 2 BOOTP broadcast 3 . . BOOTP
> broadcast 28 BOOTP broadcast 29
>
> Retry time exceeded; starting again using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN
> ep1in STATUS ep2in MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:01 HOST MAC de:ad:be:ef:00:00
> RNDIS ready musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost! high speed config
> #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS USB RNDIS network up!
>
> BOOTP broadcast 1 BOOTP broadcast 2 . . BOOTP broadcast 28 BOOTP
> broadcast 29
>
> Retry time exceeded; starting again
> =>

I am expected to get the u-boot prompt.

What can be the issue?

**EDIT-1: Adding the output of printenv as per Frant's suggestion below**

```
U-Boot SPL 2020.07-00717-gfee68b9 (Jul 17 2020 - 09:36:15)
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2020.07-00717-gfee68b9 (Jul 17 2020 - 09:36:15)

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
Model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
DRAM:  512 MiB
WDT:   Started with servicing (60s timeout)
NAND:  0 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from FAT... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Net:   eth2: ethernet@4a100000, eth3: usb_ether
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  2  0 
=>     prit ntenv
addr_fit=0x90000000
arch=arm
args_mmc=run finduuid;setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=PARTUUID=${uuid} rw rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype}
baudrate=115200
board=am335x
board_name=A335BNLT
board_rev=00C0
board_serial=2315BBBK4C31
boot_a_script=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${script}; source ${scriptaddr}
boot_efi_binary=if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi bootmgr ${fdt_addr_r};else bootefi bootmgr ${fdtcontroladdr};fi;load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${kernel_addr_r} efi/boot/bootarm.efi; if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdt_addr_r};else bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdtcontroladdr};fi
boot_extlinux=sysboot ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} any ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}
boot_fdt=try
boot_fit=0
boot_net_usb_start=usb start
boot_prefixes=/ /boot/
boot_script_dhcp=boot.scr.uimg
boot_scripts=boot.scr.uimg boot.scr
boot_syslinux_conf=extlinux/extlinux.conf
boot_targets=mmc0 legacy_mmc0 mmc1 legacy_mmc1 nand0 pxe dhcp 
bootcmd=if test ${boot_fit} -eq 1; then run update_to_fit; fi; run findfdt; run init_console; run envboot; run distro_bootcmd
bootcmd_dhcp=run boot_net_usb_start; if dhcp ${scriptaddr} ${boot_script_dhcp}; then source ${scriptaddr}; fi;setenv efi_fdtfile ${fdtfile}; if test -z "${fdtfile}" -a -n "${soc}"; then setenv efi_fdtfile ${soc}-${board}${boardver}.dtb; fi; setenv efi_old_vci ${bootp_vci};setenv efi_old_arch ${bootp_arch};setenv bootp_vci PXEClient:Arch:00010:UNDI:003000;setenv bootp_arch 0xa;if dhcp ${kernel_addr_r}; then tftpboot ${fdt_addr_r} dtb/${efi_fdtfile};if fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}; then bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdt_addr_r}; else bootefi ${kernel_addr_r} ${fdtcontroladdr};fi;fi;setenv bootp_vci ${efi_old_vci};setenv bootp_arch ${efi_old_arch};setenv efi_fdtfile;setenv efi_old_arch;setenv efi_old_vci;
bootcmd_legacy_mmc0=setenv mmcdev 0; setenv bootpart 0:2 ; run mmcboot
bootcmd_legacy_mmc1=setenv mmcdev 1; setenv bootpart 1:2 ; run mmcboot
bootcmd_mmc0=devnum=0; run mmc_boot
bootcmd_mmc1=devnum=1; run mmc_boot
bootcmd_nand=run nandboot
bootcmd_pxe=run boot_net_usb_start; dhcp; if pxe get; then pxe boot; fi
bootcount=1
bootdelay=2
bootdir=/boot
bootenvfile=uEnv.txt
bootfile=zImage
bootm_size=0x10000000
bootpart=0:2
bootscript=echo Running bootscript from mmc${mmcdev} ...; source ${loadaddr}
console=ttyO0,115200n8
cpu=armv7
dfu_alt_info_emmc=rawemmc raw 0 3751936;boot part 1 1;rootfs part 1 2;MLO fat 1 1;MLO.raw raw 0x100 0x100;u-boot.img.raw raw 0x300 0x1000;u-env.raw raw 0x1300 0x200;spl-os-args.raw raw 0x1500 0x200;spl-os-image.raw raw 0x1700 0x6900;spl-os-args fat 1 1;spl-os-image fat 1 1;u-boot.img fat 1 1;uEnv.txt fat 1 1
dfu_alt_info_mmc=boot part 0 1;rootfs part 0 2;MLO fat 0 1;MLO.raw raw 0x100 0x100;u-boot.img.raw raw 0x300 0x1000;u-env.raw raw 0x1300 0x200;spl-os-args.raw raw 0x1500 0x200;spl-os-image.raw raw 0x1700 0x6900;spl-os-args fat 0 1;spl-os-image fat 0 1;u-boot.img fat 0 1;uEnv.txt fat 0 1
dfu_alt_info_nand=SPL part 0 1;SPL.backup1 part 0 2;SPL.backup2 part 0 3;SPL.backup3 part 0 4;u-boot part 0 5;u-boot-spl-os part 0 6;kernel part 0 8;rootfs part 0 9
dfu_alt_info_ram=kernel ram 0x80200000 0x4000000;fdt ram 0x80f80000 0x80000;ramdisk ram 0x81000000 0x4000000
distro_bootcmd=for target in ${boot_targets}; do run bootcmd_${target}; done
dtboaddr=0x89000000
efi_dtb_prefixes=/ /dtb/ /dtb/current/
envboot=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; if mmc rescan; then echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev};if run loadbootscript; then run bootscript;else if run loadbootenv; then echo Loaded env from ${bootenvfile};run importbootenv;fi;if test -n $uenvcmd; then echo Running uenvcmd ...;run uenvcmd;fi;fi;fi;
eth1addr=54:4a:16:b9:a1:8e
eth2addr=54:4a:16:b9:a1:8c
eth3addr=de:ad:be:ef:00:01
ethaddr=54:4a:16:b9:a1:8c
fdt_addr_r=0x88000000
fdtaddr=0x88000000
fdtcontroladdr=9df46c60
fdtfile=undefined
findfdt=if test $board_name = A335BONE; then setenv fdtfile am335x-bone.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335BNLT; then setenv fdtfile am335x-boneblack.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335PBGL; then setenv fdtfile am335x-pocketbeagle.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBBW; then setenv fdtfile am335x-boneblack-wireless.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBG1; then setenv fdtfile am335x-bonegreen.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBGW; then setenv fdtfile am335x-bonegreen-wireless.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBBL; then setenv fdtfile am335x-boneblue.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = BBEN; then setenv fdtfile am335x-sancloud-bbe.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A33515BB; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evm.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335X_SK; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evmsk.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335_ICE; then setenv fdtfile am335x-icev2.dtb; fi; if test $fdtfile = undefined; then echo WARNING: Could not determine device tree to use; fi; 
finduuid=part uuid mmc ${bootpart} uuid
get_overlaystring=for overlay in $name_overlays;do;setenv overlaystring ${overlaystring}'#'${overlay};done;
importbootenv=echo Importing environment from mmc${mmcdev} ...; env import -t ${loadaddr} ${filesize}
init_console=if test $board_name = A335_ICE; then setenv console ttyO3,115200n8;else setenv console ttyO0,115200n8;fi;
kernel_addr_r=0x82000000
load_efi_dtb=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${fdt_addr_r} ${prefix}${efi_fdtfile}
loadaddr=0x82000000
loadbootenv=fatload mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} ${bootenvfile}
loadbootscript=load mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} boot.scr
loadfdt=load ${devtype} ${bootpart} ${fdtaddr} ${bootdir}/${fdtfile}
loadimage=load ${devtype} ${bootpart} ${loadaddr} ${bootdir}/${bootfile}
loadramdisk=load mmc ${mmcdev} ${rdaddr} ramdisk.gz
mmc_boot=if mmc dev ${devnum}; then devtype=mmc; run scan_dev_for_boot_part; fi
mmcboot=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; devnum=${mmcdev}; setenv devtype mmc; if mmc rescan; then echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev};if run loadimage; then run args_mmc; if test ${boot_fit} -eq 1; then run run_fit; else run mmcloados;fi;fi;fi;
mmcdev=0
mmcloados=if test ${boot_fdt} = yes || test ${boot_fdt} = try; then if run loadfdt; then bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}; else if test ${boot_fdt} = try; then bootz; else echo WARN: Cannot load the DT; fi; fi; else bootz; fi;
mmcrootfstype=ext4 rootwait
mtdids=nand0=nand.0
mtdparts=mtdparts=nand.0:128k(NAND.SPL),128k(NAND.SPL.backup1),128k(NAND.SPL.backup2),128k(NAND.SPL.backup3),256k(NAND.u-boot-spl-os),1m(NAND.u-boot),128k(NAND.u-boot-env),128k(NAND.u-boot-env.backup1),8m(NAND.kernel),-(NAND.file-system)
name_fit=fitImage
nandargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${nandroot} rootfstype=${nandrootfstype}
nandboot=echo Booting from nand ...; run nandargs; nand read ${fdtaddr} NAND.u-boot-spl-os; nand read ${loadaddr} NAND.kernel; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
nandroot=ubi0:rootfs rw ubi.mtd=NAND.file-system,2048
nandrootfstype=ubifs rootwait=1
netargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=${serverip}:${rootpath},${nfsopts} rw ip=dhcp
netboot=echo Booting from network ...; setenv autoload no; dhcp; run netloadimage; run netloadfdt; run netargs; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
netloadfdt=tftp ${fdtaddr} ${fdtfile}
netloadimage=tftp ${loadaddr} ${bootfile}
nfsopts=nolock
partitions=uuid_disk=${uuid_gpt_disk};name=bootloader,start=384K,size=1792K,uuid=${uuid_gpt_bootloader};name=rootfs,start=2688K,size=-,uuid=${uuid_gpt_rootfs}
pxefile_addr_r=0x80100000
ramargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${ramroot} rootfstype=${ramrootfstype}
ramboot=echo Booting from ramdisk ...; run ramargs; bootz ${loadaddr} ${rdaddr} ${fdtaddr}
ramdisk_addr_r=0x88080000
ramroot=/dev/ram0 rw
ramrootfstype=ext2
rdaddr=0x88080000
rootpath=/export/rootfs
run_fit=bootm ${addr_fit}#${fdtfile}${overlaystring}
scan_dev_for_boot=echo Scanning ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart}...; for prefix in ${boot_prefixes}; do run scan_dev_for_extlinux; run scan_dev_for_scripts; done;run scan_dev_for_efi;
scan_dev_for_boot_part=part list ${devtype} ${devnum} -bootable devplist; env exists devplist || setenv devplist 1; for distro_bootpart in ${devplist}; do if fstype ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} bootfstype; then run scan_dev_for_boot; fi; done; setenv devplist
scan_dev_for_efi=setenv efi_fdtfile ${fdtfile}; if test -z "${fdtfile}" -a -n "${soc}"; then setenv efi_fdtfile ${soc}-${board}${boardver}.dtb; fi; for prefix in ${efi_dtb_prefixes}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${efi_fdtfile}; then run load_efi_dtb; fi;done;if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} efi/boot/bootarm.efi; then echo Found EFI removable media binary efi/boot/bootarm.efi; run boot_efi_binary; echo EFI LOAD FAILED: continuing...; fi; setenv efi_fdtfile
scan_dev_for_extlinux=if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; then echo Found ${prefix}${boot_syslinux_conf}; run boot_extlinux; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi
scan_dev_for_scripts=for script in ${boot_scripts}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${distro_bootpart} ${prefix}${script}; then echo Found U-Boot script ${prefix}${script}; run boot_a_script; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi; done
scriptaddr=0x80000000
serial#=2315BBBK4C31
soc=am33xx
spiargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${spiroot} rootfstype=${spirootfstype}
spiboot=echo Booting from spi ...; run spiargs; sf probe ${spibusno}:0; sf read ${loadaddr} ${spisrcaddr} ${spiimgsize}; bootz ${loadaddr}
spibusno=0
spiimgsize=0x362000
spiroot=/dev/mtdblock4 rw
spirootfstype=jffs2
spisrcaddr=0xe0000
static_ip=${ipaddr}:${serverip}:${gatewayip}:${netmask}:${hostname}::off
stderr=serial@44e09000
stdin=serial@44e09000
stdout=serial@44e09000
update_to_fit=setenv loadaddr ${addr_fit}; setenv bootfile ${name_fit}
usb_boot=usb start; if usb dev ${devnum}; then devtype=usb; run scan_dev_for_boot_part; fi
usbnet_devaddr=de:ad:be:ef:00:01
vendor=ti
ver=U-Boot 2020.07-00717-gfee68b9 (Jul 17 2020 - 09:36:15)

Environment size: 9963/131068 bytes
=>
```

Comment: You need to recompile with `CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=-1` in  `configs/am335x_evm_defconfig`, re-install u-boot on your Beaglebone Black, and reboot. This will cause u-boot to stop, and you will get a prompt.

Then execute the `printenv`command  and augment your question with its output, formated as code (no screenshot please). Basically, the `serverip` variable  is not set, your device is attempting to boot using  `serverip`, and it fails.

Comment: Hi Frant, thanks a ton. Will follow your instructions and append the output to my question. I indeed tried to format the above output as code. However, SO did not allow and i had no other option but to put it in blockquotes. Anyways, I'll post as code next time.

Comment: Hi Frant, appended the output of printenv for the current u-boot build to the question.